# DidRefreshRegistrationToken not called, even after uninstall /install. How get an already generated firebase token in xamarin IOS,

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin

I lose the token I was using for testing, I uninstall the app, and run it again but DidRefreshRegistrationToken is not called, so I can not get the token. The strange thing is that if I send a message from the firebase console to all IOS, the notification arrives, so, this mean that the app has a valid token? if so, how I get it, or how to refresh it?

Comment: You can retrieve the token directly using GetId:. This callback provides an identity, which contains the token. A non null error is provided if the InstanceID retrieval failed in any way.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to use GetId?